# Robolectric Custom Shadow Object

Tags: android, android-emulator, mocking, robolectric

OOTB, [Robolectric](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) does not support Locales that well. Therefore, if your app is dependent on locales (which a lot of apps are if they are i18n'nd properly) this can be a royal pain. Long story short, I created my own ShadowFooGeocoder and ShadowFooAddress that allow me to simulate the locale I want. They're basically re-implementations of the existing shadows.

However, when I bind my class as such: bindShadowClass(ShadowFooGeocoder.class), this works great. At runtime, the correct shadow is returned. The problem is that I want to set up the simulations on this object and I'm not sure how. shadowOf(instance) where instance is an injected GeoCoder returns ShadowGeoCoder. I've tried working directly with the ShadowWrangler, but that also returns a ShadowGeocoder.

How can I get at my shadowed class that I've bound through the bindShadowClass(...) call so I can set my expectations (simulations)?

Note: This is a repost of the same question on the Robolectric group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robolectric/i1BaUCI8e7U). I posted here because my success rate of getting anyone to answer questions on the group is fairly low. I'm hoping for a better result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've basically done here is extend ShadowGeocoder like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"UnusedDeclaration"})
@Implements(Geocoder.class)
public class ShadowFooBarGeocoder extends ShadowGeocoder {
  // implementation stuff
}
```

Then I would bind it using the bindShadowClasss(...) and when I retreive the shadow via the static shadowOf(...) call I get back a "ShadowGeocoder" which is an instance of ShadowFooBarGeocoder. I then cast it to that type and perform whatever work I need to.

Comment: Looks like the bindShadowClasss approach will not work with the latest robolectric version. 
Could you suggest what could be the new approach?